# If I want to learn javascript by small project, what should I do?

Tags: javascript

I found javascript is not so easy to master. And I want to dive into it. I think learning by using is a good way. Since javascript is different from other C-style language, what kind of project is good for learning?

Thanks.

Comment: The usual: Something that you find sufficiently interesting to motivate yourself to finish the project.

Comment: @David Wait, you *finish* projects?

Comment: @silky — rarely, I also suffer from an urge to overengineer and have many shiny distractions near where I do personal projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take up any project that involves an interactive UI, then build it as a web page.
It will give you a lot to learn about js, from syntax to event handling.

E.g: a calculator

Comment: A very good suggestion, encapsulates user input, asynchronicity, responding to events, logic...

Comment: A calculator is actually how I first went beyond the basics of JavaScript. Then I discovered jQuery and realized that I wasted my time.

Comment: I really like the idea of calculator

Answer (score 1):

Since it's inevitable that people will suggest learning resources (whereas the question is about *projects*, here's a CW answer for people to use to list those resources.

#### Books

- *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* (5th ed.) by David Flanagan. Good book from a good author. Getting a bit dated.

#### Online Resources

- [The Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (brand new 5th edition spec is out!). The language is turgid, but when you want to know *exactly* how something is supposed to work...
- http://javascript.crockford.com/ Douglas Crockford is immensely knowledgeable about JavaScript. Not everyone (*myself included — T.J.*) agrees with all of Crockford's conclusions, especially around things like the `new` operator, but he does know his stuff and so if you take his various essays as observations to think about, not gospel, he's very educational and thought-provoking.
- [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The first project I'd do is get JsUnit working and figure out how I'm going to run the tests I write for the rest of the project on a regular basis (as in, simulated or real continuous integration).

Comment: Aren't unit tests a bit advanced for someone just getting into JavaScript?

Comment: I had to type these characters so that I could get to the answer: No.  Since writing a good test is the most critical skill that any developer can have, it makes sense that it should be the first one that starts to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your age:
Playing around with Canvas might be a good start.  The way I learned AS2 [which has similar functions and ECMAScript-style syntax, like JavaScript] was by creating a "Canvas"(MovieClip) and playing around with lineTo and moveTo.

With that, you could write simple games like Pong [my first AS2 game] with a simple AI...

Embarking on this project would cover:

1. User Input
2. Graphics
3. Variables
4. Flow Control
5. setTimeout
6. Logic
7. Collision detection

Pong is a great first project, because you can customize it all that you want.  When I wrote my version, I made it so by holding Enter, you could place a block in the middle of the screen, that the ball would bounce off of.  The possibilities are basically endless =/

---

If you're interested in more "classic" web development [non-RIA things]
You could go for a simple lights-out game, which would take around 30 minutes to write.

Comment: Is it too difficult to master? How much time will it take?

Comment: Lights out is a very easy game to write.  It just requires you draw equally sized squares in a grid =/  Simple collision detection [mouse in square?] is probably the most advanced thing you'll do >_>