# What (kind of) project could I create to learn JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, projects

I started learning JavaScript a while ago. It's a fairly easy programming language considering that I learned Java in university, that I know php pretty well and that I already played around with python and ruby. The problem is that to properly learn a programming language I usually create a project. In javascript, I just don't know what kind of project I could create  - that is, a project that is not web-based or related to the web browser. Can I create javascript shell scripts? Where is javascript commonly used beside the web browsers?

So, can someone actually give me some ideas please?

Comment: Believe it or not, a *very similar* question was just asked by another user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528508/if-i-want-to-learn-javascript-by-small-project-what-should-i-do If that answers your question, recommend deleting this one. If not, suggest posting back to say you've read it but are still looking for ideas.

Comment: JavaScript is an EASY language... I guess it depends how you use it... I think that could be said for any language... its "easy" if you use it to write a Hello World application...

Comment: Zoidberg: Javascript is a small language, but it takes infinite amount of time to learn the in's and out's of it. Closures, Prototypical Inheritance, etc etc.

Comment: @Zoidberg & @Matt: I think you're both right. It's an easy language to pick up, and a demanding (and rewarding) language to master.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I have work to do now: javascript shell scripts, OS X Dashboard widgets and HTA applications it will be!

Comment: @T.J. Kinda like what they say about Poker, 15 minutes to learn, a life-time to master.

Comment: @Zoidberg: Yeah. :-) Poker, Chess, Go...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I create javascript shell scripts?

You bet!

- On Windows, you can do this by using `cscript.exe` (you can even set up a file extension -- I use `jx` -- that automatically runs when you just double-click the filename or use it as a command in a shell: Just associate that file extension with the command `"c:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe" /e:JavaScript /nologo "%1" %*`). This is (and I've measured carefully) about 80 milion times better than fighting with Windows' batch language. About. (And if you don't want to use JScript — Microsoft's variant of JavaScript — you even have options, see below.)
- On *nix, a shell script can be set to run in any installed interpreter (that's what the `#!...` line at the top is telling the command interpreter). I expect you'll find a few if you search around.
- On the Mac, you probably have [JavaScriptCore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore) installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc`
- And on all of the above, if you like, you can install [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) and Java and get platform independence and access to a huge range of library functionality. Rhino has a built-in shell, or you can tell it to execute a specific JavaScript file. It interoperates with Java, so if you do this, you have *easy* access to all essentially of the functionality available to Java.

> Where is javascript commonly used beside the web browsers?

I use it for shell scripting on Windows. I also use it as a server-side language, for instance in the server-side part of a web application. It's also used in other environments where a lightweight, powerful scripting language is useful, such as in the [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) shell environment (you can use it to query MongoDB data) and stored procedures.

All of that said, writing a browser-based project is a rich, interactive way to learn the language.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder This all sounds very nice, but how on earth can javascript execute shell command lets say "uptime" in *nix, with what will you execute it? if you have php file you can execute it with `php file.php` , how do you execute javascript? `javascript file.js` ? I think you can't or perhaps I don't know how

Comment: @c0mrade: It depends on what interpreter you're using to make it happen. For instance, on Windows, you can use the various WSH objects to do that. If using Rhino, you'd use the `java.lang.Process` or similar. I'm sure `jsc` provides functionality along these lines. You're confusing *language* with *runtime environment*. :-)

Comment: yea totally, tnx for the explanation though

Comment: @c0mrade: Actually, sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. You can run a JavaScript files as a shell script on Windows in the way I explain in my answer. On *nix, the usual thing would be to set up an interpreter (for instance, it could be `/bin/javascript` if you like) and then use `#!/bin/javascript` at the top of the script to tell the command interpreter what to run it with (this is just like with python and others). That would refer to `jsc` (probably) on a Mac, could refer to Rhino on Linux, or something else. There are lots of JavaScript interpreter projects out there. :-)

Answer (score 4):

windows Sidebar Gadgets, Apple's Widgets, and Google Desktop Gadgets are all created using HTML/ JS/ CSS.

I learnt Javascript by creating a few small Windows Sidebar Gadgets.

[Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163370.aspx)

[Sidebar Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723264(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript to make HTA (HTML Applications) that can be run outside of the the web browser sandbox. 
 [MSDN intro to HTA Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx)
[Javascript Tutorial on HTML Applications](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/HTML_Applications.htm)

Comment: Older technologies I know but still can be fun none the less.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a non-blocking TCP server.
[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api.html#_tcp) supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Common uses of javascript outside of browsers are WSH scripts and HTA applications on Windows and Dashboard widgets on Mac.